# Terraform nginx ingress dynamic for_each rules host

Tags: terraform, nginx-ingress

Trying to create a dynamic host rules that I previously had in my ingress yaml file. Main difference TF doesn't have 'rules' they have a single 'rule', but I assume it's just a naming conversion. Currently im creating an ingress for each item, but I'd like to do a dynamic rule. I understand the dynamic has to be in a resource/data/etc. How would I accomplish this? (not a working example)

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "test" {

  wait_for_load_balancer = false
  metadata {
    name = "my-test-${each.value}"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.test.metadata.0.name
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx"
    }
  }

  spec {
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = toset(var.types)
      content {
        host = "${each.value}.test.mydomain.com"
        http {
          path {
            path = "/"
            backend {
              service_name = kubernetes_service.test[each.value].metadata.0.name
              service_port = 8080
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html), you have to use, in your case, `rule`, not `each` to refer to items in your `for_each`:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "test" {

  #..

  spec {
    dynamic "rule" {
      for_each = toset(var.types)
      content {
        host = "${rule.value}.test.mydomain.com"
        http {
          path {
            path = "/"
            backend {
              service_name = kubernetes_service.test[rule.value].metadata.0.name
              service_port = 8080
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was not clear in the documentation.